# How do I use return statements from a method as a parameter to another method?

Tags: java, parameters, return-value

I'm using a class variable, which I assigned a value in a method return. When I'm trying to use the return value as a parameter for another method it gives an error unless I declare the return statements again, which means I'd be creating a new local variable I'm guessing, and not using the class variable. So is it possible to use the return value, instead of ending up declaring a new variable.

I'm just asking whether it's possible. If it is, then there's probably something else wrong with my code.

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

When you have method `returnOne` do this:

```
public int returnOne() {
    return 1;
}
```

And you have another method `isOne` like this:

```
public boolean isOne(int number) {
    return (number == 1)
}
```

You can use the result of `returnOne` in `isOne` as a parameter like this:

```
boolean result = isOne(returnOne());
```

Hope this helps!